# Correct link rel CSS stylesheet not being implemented for a menu

Tags: php, css, require

I have `menu.php`, and in the `<head>` section of `menu.php`, I have `menu.css` as a `link rel` tag of course, both of which work perfectly fine.

Since `menu.php` is a 'menu', I've `require`d it on pages that need a 'menu' in order to navigate around the website. However, whenever I `require` menu.php on a page that has its **own** CSS stylesheet, `menu.php` inherits the `<body>` font-size of the **other** stylesheet.

Here is what I'm trying to say: So if I `require` `menu.php` on `profile.php`, `menu.php` elements will become the size of `profile.css`, instead of what they really ought to be(`menu.css`). How can I fix the following problem? Currently, I am `requiring` `menu.php` BEFORE the `<html>` tag.

Should I put this within `<head>`? Somewhere else?

Thank you.

---

Some of the code from `menu.php:`

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I've put my PHP code before the `<html>` tag in the file above.

The below code comes from `main.php`:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Euhm, by all means, create valid HTML (content before the <html> tag?), validate both HTML & CSS with the w3c validator, and it that doesn't work, ask at http://doctype.com/

Comment: Tip: Consider using a template engine such as Smarty.

Comment: By the way, I am requiring 'menu.php' into 'main.php' so I could see why this trouble is happening...there are two stylesheets for one page hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you include a complete html page generated by `menu.php` before the html in `main.php`. That would get you 2 `<html>` sections, 2 `<body>` sections, etc. in one document. That should lead to lots of trouble.

You should include your menu in for example a `div` inside the main page like (just an example):

main.php:

```
<body>
<div id="nav">
<?php require 'menu.php'; ?>
</div>
...
</body>
```

and put all menu styles in the main style-sheet, pre-fixed with `#nav`. Or as a separate style-sheet, but still pre-fixed with `#nav` (every style) so that they overwrite the main document's styles.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste the content of your menu.php? Because if there are  and  section there...you're doing it wrong, because in that way you're going to have two head and two body parts. Think for require in php as copy and paste.

Your options:

- Migrate to some template system(as Smarty for example).
- If there should be menu.php on each page, why not putting this css as static file in the header
- Paste some code, so we could help you easier ;)

Comment: @ Vladimiroff - I've added the code from my files in the edited section. Thank you.